# Unable to set isOn property of a UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I would like to call my UISwitch from a different location without the action being triggered.

The point of the code is when a button or viewselect is selected it will disable certain switches.

Something along the lines of:

```
IBACTION func myswitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
}

IBACTION func my button(_ sender : UIButton) {
    myswicth.isOn = True
}
```

It keeps saying value of type UISwitch has no arg isOn or isEnable.

Comment: Please show real code and exact, complete error messages in your question. When you show rough pseudo code and partial messages it is hard to be sure what your real problem is.

Comment: IBACTION?  What is it?  Or is it supposed to be @IBAction?

Comment: @IBAction, there is no errors i just need a way to do so

Answer (score 0):

You're always setting the value of the `mySwitch.isOn` to `true`. Update it like the following below to set it to disabled or enabled for every time you press your button:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    mySwitch.isOn = !mySwitch.isOn
}
```

Alternatively add in additional logic depending on when you would like your switch to be enabled/disabled.

Comment: The question is about compiler errors, not incorrect functionality at runtime.

Comment: this occurs          Value of type '(UISwitch) -> ()' has no member 'isOn'

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, not enough clear information to understand this properly.

Comment: @C.Britton how are you declaring mySwitch?

Comment: @irs8925  im declaring it as a action .   IBAction func mySwitch(_ sender : 
 UISwictch) { }